# Memory overflow？

Tags: c++, memory, com, java-native-interface

i hava a c++ method(for java,jni) like follow，when i repeat call this from java (every 150ms),about after 4 hours. Memory overflow....

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_nc_mes_pub_hardware_PCI1761_readChanel
(JNIEnv *, jobject, jint channel){

```
HRESULT hr ; 

CLSID   clsid;
hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"AdvDIO.AdvDIOCtrl",   &clsid);

CComPtr<IAdvDIO>  advlib;

hr = advlib.CoCreateInstance(clsid);

if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
{ 
    advlib->DeviceNumber = 0;

    if(advlib->DeviceNumber < 0){
        return -100;
    }
    int i =advlib->ReadDiChannel( channel );
    // advlib.Release();
    advlib = NULL;
    return i;
}
else
{
    return -1;
}
```

}

Comment: Why is the code line // advlib.Release(); commented out ?? Have you tried your function with that line used as active code ?

Comment: yes,this is the originally code.Then Memory overflow. so i comment it...

Comment: i think the CComPtr don't need to release manually.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
advlib = NULL;
```

The `advlib` object needs the correct value in order to do its job. By destroying its value and setting it to NULL, it can no longer free the correct instance.

Uncommenting `advlib.Release()` will likely make it work. But the correct fix is to remove the 
`advlib = NULL;` and allow the `CComPtr` to do its job.

Comment: remove advlib = NULL;? like this?                                      int i =advlib->ReadDiChannel( channel );                         return i;

Comment: Correct. At that point in the code, `advlib` owns resources whose values it contains so that it can release them. If you destroy it by setting it equal to `NULL`, it can't free those resources because it no longer contains their values. Think of `advlib` at that point as a "TO DO" list with "free resources" on the list. You set it equal to NULL, erasing that list. So it never frees those resources.